# How Does Stackoverflow Restrict Questions - IP Address?

Tags: node.js, security, ip-address

Hope this question is in the right place.

A couple of years back I remember going crazy and asking > x number of questions in a month on StackOverflow (I learnt my lesson) however was wondering how this is implemented.

What i also noticed was - if I used another email or even facebook account - on my same home network connection it gave the same error - you cannot post more than x in a month.

I'm building a Node/Angular app and wanting to do the same.

So straight off my head I guess I could watch/record the IP Address however how would this handle situations like a large network where multiple users are connected (e.g. University halls) - I presume they would all have the same IP address?

Interested to learn how its implemented or any other solutions (or ideas) to this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you need to login before asking any question they simply save whatever they need to do DB along with your account info

Comment: What i also noticed was - if I used another email or even facebook account - on my same home network connection it gave the same error - you cannot post more than x in a month.

Comment: Well they can also use cookies and maybe localStorage. I think if you used different browser or incognito mode in chrome with another account they wouldn't know it's still you

Comment: I tried on a different laptop

Comment: With new account? Or one you already used.

Comment: There's no way they would use IP address since it's not unique for single user.

Comment: So why on using a different laptop, my friends Google+ account I couldn't post.

Comment: Check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260168